# What is the 'source()' equivalent in DeployR?

Tags: r, server, deployr

I am trying to link 3 scripts on a **DeployR** server, however, everytime I use `source('PATH')` I get an error `can not open the connection`.

I tried the function `load()` and same result.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: I am using the web portal

Comment: I mean R is running in which environment? Windows? Be careful with / or \.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can understand, you should Load all scripts first. 
So, with button Load and choose them from repository or local machine. 
Then call:
source("script.R")

Hope that's help.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know the path for the file that (I was using a remote service)